# How to professionally spell library names such as "scikit learn"?

Tags: scikit-learn, library

For example for inclusion in a CV. This is mostly a question of whether one should use capital letters or not.

Usually I search the library to find how the library name is spelled on the official page.

For scikit-learn it is spelled without capital letter, while most of the other letter has some capital letter at the beginning (and often inside as well). Still it doesn't feel right next to other capitalised names.

Should I still use a capital "Scikit-Learn" or am I overthinking this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scikit-learn has a citation guide: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/about.html#citing-scikit-learn

They spell it with a uppercase "S" and lowercase "l":

> Scikit-learn: Machine Learning in Python

Comment: Thanks I didn't think about looking at that.

Comment: But elsewhere on that page, and throughout the paper, the do not capitalize the S. It's just for the title-case.

Answer (score 1):

Following the link in zachdj's answer, they spell it with a lowercase "s" and lowercase "l" in both papers appearing in the citation guide provided. Here is an example found in the paper [Scikit-learn: Machine Learning in Python](https://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/v12/pedregosa11a.html), Pedregosa et al., JMLR 12, pp. 2825-2830, 2011:

> While scikit-learn focuses on ease of use, and is mostly written in a high level language, care has been taken to maximize computational efficiency.